# Problemas al cargar las librerias de sweet alert javascript

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Estoy tratando de cargar las librerías en un servidor local pero por alguna extraña razón no cargan.

Sin embargo si lo cargo desde codepen o desde stackoverflow funciona sin problemas... Deseo que me carguen localmente.

A continuación el código

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script>
  swal("Hello world!");
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a acceder desde un navegador a la ruta del js? Así descartas que tengas cortado el acceso al js.

Comment: Luis por favor abri la pagina donde no te carga Sweet, da click derecho inspeccionar y anda a Console te sale alguno de estos errores? Uncaught (in promise) SweetAlert: You can only use SweetAlert AFTER the DOM has loaded! o este Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaria, acceder al enlace, copiar el codigo que te muestra y guardarlo dentro de tu carpeta de proyecto, y solo sustituyes en el `script` por la direccion donde lo guardaste.

```
<script src="direccion de carpeta/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo resolví localmente fue agregando todas las etiquetas html es decir.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <body>

<script>
  swal("Error!", "Esto es un mensaje!", "error");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```